# Paperclip and nested forms, getting duplicate entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-forms

We're trying to upload multiple images to our Product model through the Paperclip gem. Problem is, that everytime we submit the form, each of the existing images already attached to the product, gets added again, but without any attributes. We have created the following nested form:

```
<div class="product-form">
    <%= nested_form_for [:admin, @product], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :category %><br>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id]}, :include_blank => true %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :price %><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :discount %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :discount, :step => "any" %><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %><br>
    </div>

    <table>
        <%= f.fields_for :stocks %> 
        <tr>
            <td><%= f.link_to_add "Add size", :stocks %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <%= f.fields_for :images %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= f.link_to_add "Add image", :images %></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

Which looks for the following partial:

```
<tr>
    <% if f.object.new_record? %>
        <td><%= f.file_field :image %></td>
    <% else  %>
      <td><%= f.object.image_file_name   %></td>
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <td><%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

Image model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :product

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100" }, 
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

end
```

Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Associations
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :carts, :through => :line_items
    has_many :stocks, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :images, :dependent  => :destroy
    belongs_to :category
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks, :images, :allow_destroy => true

    # Validations
    validates_presence_of :name, :price, :description, :category

    def create_stock(size, amount)
        Stock.create(size: size, amount: amount, product: self)
    end

    def self.categories     
        Product.pluck(:category).uniq
    end

    def sizes_in_stock
        stocks.where.not(amount: 0).map{ |s| s.size }
    end

    def price_after_discount
        has_discount? ? (self.price * self.discount/100).round(2) : price
    end

    def has_discount?
        !self.discount.nil?
    end

end
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Post your `full view code` please.

Comment: How it looks for a partial if you not specified any render in the main code>

Comment: what render are you referring to?

Comment: You said 'Which looks for the following partial' how if there is no `render :partial 'file_name'` in the main view code

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: @Pavan the gem does that automatically